# Detecting hash change using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function when the hash changes using pure JavaScript. I tried putting this function on `document.ready` but it didn't work.

```
function hashHandler(){
    this.oldHash = window.location.hash;
    this.Check;

    var that = this;
    var detect = function(){
        if(that.oldHash!=window.location.hash){
            alert("HASH CHANGED - new has" + window.location.hash);
            that.oldHash = window.location.hash;
        }
    };
    this.Check = setInterval(function(){ detect() }, 100);
}
```

Comment: On which event are you triggering the function?

Comment: "Pure Javascript"? As in [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/), or don't you even want to use the appropriate DOM function such as [`window.addEventListener('hashchange', …)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onhashchange)?

Comment: im writing an extension for a website that when visiting other pages of that website, it only reloads a certain div, not the entire website. i would use anything that doesn't have me download and install something extra, i'm already using jquery so thats fair game. nothing i've tried works so far, even the 'duplicate' question.